# Question about inner product of functions from a group to a field.

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, vector-spaces, inner-products, symmetric-groups

In *The Symmetric Group* the author, Bruce Sagan, writes on page 35 that the definition of the inner product is
$$
\langle\chi,\psi\rangle=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum\limits_{g\in G}\chi(g)\psi(g^{-1}),
$$
where $\chi, \psi$ are functions from a group $G$ to an arbitrary field. **However**, he goes on to write '*but over the complex numbers this "inner product" is only a bilinear form*'. I do not understand what he means by that. It seems like he starts by saying that we define the inner product for an arbitrary field, but it does not apply to the complex numbers, which is quite confusing. Can someone help me understand what he means?

Comment: Over the reals, inner products are bilinear forms. But over the complex numbers, inner products are sesquilinear forms. The inner product presented here is a bilinear form, but not a sesquilinear one.

Comment: Just take into account that Sagan writes "inner product" because in general it is *not* an inner product in the sense of linear algebra, as in arbitrary fields we have no "positive" or "negative" (for example, in the complex  $\;\Bbb C\;$ )

Comment: So the fact that it is a bilinear form is just a side note, and he is not saying that the definition does not apply when considering the complex numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are rightly confused here. It happens that Sagan uses the expression "inner product" in a non standard way. Usually, inner products are only defined over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. Over $\mathbb{R}$ an inner product is a bilinear map $B$ from $V\times V$ (where $V$ is a real vector space) into $\mathbb{R}$ which is symmetric and such that $B(v,v)>0$ when $v\in V\setminus\{0\}$. But the definition is different over $\mathbb{C}$. Then $B$ must be sesquilinear (meaning that it preserves sums for each variable and that $B(\alpha v,\beta w)=\alpha\overline\beta B(v,w)$) and conjugate symmetric (meaning that $B(w,v)=\overline{B(v,w)}$).

Comment: In each variable -> in its first argument, no?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I meant that it preserves sums and I have edited what I wrote. Thank you.